# Checkbox in an email

Tags: c#, html, checkbox, mailmessage

I am creating an email using the c# MailMessage and I am trying to add a checkbox that doesn't need to be clicked. The checkboxes will be used for a checklist of what to bring to an event (like a packing list). I have:

```
MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage();
objEmail.From = new MailAddress("sender@hotmail.com");
objEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress("example1@hotmail.com"));
objEmail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("example2@hotmail.com"));
objEmail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("example3@hotmail.com"));

objEmail.Subject = "Packing list!";
objEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;

objEmail.Body = @"<div width=""800px"">
    <h3>WHAT TO BRING</h3>
    <form>
        <input type=""checkbox"" name=""item"" value=""shirt"">Shirt<br>
        <input type=""checkbox"" name=""item"" value=""shoes"">Shoes 
    </form></div>";
```

but when I send the email the checkboxes do not appear in the list.
 

Output in outlook using outlook.com:

## WHAT TO BRING

I have a bike
I have a car

Output in outlook using Microsoft Outlook:

## WHAT TO BRING

[ ]I have a bike
[ ]I have a car

Output in outlook using hotmail.com:

## WHAT TO BRING

I have a bike
[]I have a car

So the problem is with the mail client but it is inconsistent what the problem is. I s there any way to make a consistent output?
 Is there a way with html that works to create the checkboxes or do I just need to include images of a checkbox?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say the mail format has something to do with it.

Comment: How does it arrive as plain-text ?

Comment: Does maybe your mail client filter out the controls?

Comment: @Prix I updated the question with several outputs of what I get

Comment: @Basuro It does appear to be the client, is there any way to change the code to overcome the filters?

Comment: Not sure have you checked their configuration too see if they have an option to show html, or if that is set by default and also if they block html code from suspected sources ?

Comment: @Austin If this is for more than just private, I would suggest you to create a webform on a web server and send the url to the clients.

Comment: @Prix It's showing other html code in the emails, in the original email I'm including a couple pictures and using ul and those both work. In this example I'm using h1 and that works as well. Just not the checkboxes.

Comment: @Fabian Bigler The code posted in the question is just part of the email. I was trying to place the checklist in a section of the email for easier access

Comment: I don't think images would resolve the issue either as most clients would not open images by default so whoever gets the email would only see it if they are whiling to approve it. I would do as @FabianBigler suggested above.

Comment: @Austin You can not determine how a mail client will parse your mailmessages, especially regarding inputcontrols like checkboxes. As you can see in your own question - every mail client shows your checkboxes differently.

Comment: @Prix@Fabian Bigler Thanks guys, I think I'm going to use logixologist's answer to avoid having the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that their in inconsistency with the way the email clients handle check boxes.

Why not change each to [X] which is plain text so all email clients can see it.

Comment: I might end up doing it this way. I was trying to follow a format my boss set for me but it might not be possible to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook.com has an issue to display multiple check or radio buttons within a single parent.  /  /  / etc
add a table in there and add the 2 check boxes in a separate row and it should work fine.

weird Microsoft thinking

Answer (score -1):

All email clients have their own rules on what's allowed. You may find that most providers don't allow JavaScript and just some allow positioning elements while some don't.

Your best bet is to use a plain text form or maybe an image of what the form looks like. And when I say image, don't mean make the entire thing an image, have images for each checkbox. Once you click anywhere in this form it opens up on your site to interact with it.

Furthermore, you really shouldn't be building html in your code like you are. Put that in an MVC view or a webforms partial and invoke the file from code. Using this approach you can still inject dynamic data into the template while putting the HTML where it belongs.