# add html checkbox via outlook addin (c#)

Tags: c#, checkbox, outlook, vsto

I create a mail in outlook via an addin (VSTO).(request for instrument maintenance)
I want to use checkboxes for the customer to check if he wants exta service.`

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector inspi = this.Context as 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem openMail = inspi.CurrentItem as 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
[...]
openMail.HTMLBody += @"<input type = ""checkbox"" name = ""item1"">Extra1<br>";
openMail.HTMLBody += @"<input type = ""checkbox"" name = ""item2"">Extra2<br>";
openMail.HTMLBody += @"<input type = ""checkbox"" name = ""item2"">Extra3<br>";
```

But no real checkboxes are created, only squarebrackets with space in between.

> [ ]

Can I create real checkboxes via VSTO?

Comment: Did your read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453577/checkbox-in-an-email) SO question?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word to renter HTML messages. It does not run embedded scripts and does not allow HTML forms.